# I added a custom function to a prototype but my IDE not recognize the function, what can i do?

Tags: javascript

I am using Webstorm IDE and I created a custom function for the prototype Boolean.

```js
Boolean.prototype.toStringTF = (): keyof TF => this ? "true" : "false";
console.log(Boolean(import.meta.env.PROD).toStringTF());
const isProduction: keyof typeof beforeSendObject = Boolean(import.meta.env.PROD).toStringTF();
```

The function works perfectly, but the IDE dosnt recognize the function on the prototype.

Thanks for the help!